# ¿Existe algún término de uso extendido en español, para el término en inglés "emotionally invested"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, psicología

En inglés se usa el término "emotionally invested" para cuando uno pone muchas ganas, esfuerzo o expectativas en alguna relación o en alguna otra actividad (como un hobbie o un trabajo, supongo). ¿Existe algún término de uso común en español para algo así?

Ejemplo de uso:

> When you are **emotionally invested** in someone, they have become
>   intricately interwoven into the tapestry of your life—a big part of
>   your big picture

Se me ocurre la traducción literal *emocionalmente invertido*, pero en la vida escuché este término en español.

Comment: ¿ y que tal simplemente **"Enamorado"** ?

Comment: The example you quote has made some people think the English phrase can only apply with a person as the object but you can have emotional investment in a cause (for instance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

¿Qué tal `emocionalmente implicado` ?

Parece ajustarse a la definición. Se puede prescindir del adverbio y decir solo "implicado", o "muy implicado", ya que se sobreentiende el resto, yo creo.

Comment: También "emocionalmente involucrado".

Answer (score 4):

**Tener [mucho] apego**.  Saqué esta idea de linguee.com.  Linguée sugirió *apego emocional* -- yo lo simplifico porque "emocional" me parece redundante.

Dos ideas para tu frase:

> Cuando tienes *mucho apego* a una persona, esa persona etc.
>
> Cuando estás *muy apegado* a una persona, esa persona etc.

**Edit**: Se me ocurrió otra cosa.

**Emocionalmente comprometido**

> Cuando estás muy *emocionalmente comprometido* a una persona, esa persona etc.

La verdad es que esta frase me parece más preciso y además mejor para el contexto (psicología un tanto *pop*).

Answer (score -1):

Simplemente [enamorado](http://dle.rae.es/srv/fetch?id=Ev9TuQ5).

En la RAE encontramos:

> enamorado, da. Del part. de enamorar.
>
> 1. adj. Que siente amor y atracción sexual por alguien. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Propio de una persona enamorada. Mirada enamorada.
> 3. adj. Muy aficionado a algo o muy amante de ello. U. t. c. s. Un enamorado de la música y de su pueblo.
> 4. adj. enamoradizo. U. m. en Am.
> 5. adj. Am. Que mantiene con otra persona una relación más o menos amorosa y sin compromiso formal para el matrimonio.
> 6. f. desus. prostituta.

La acepción 3 es exactamente eso y en el caso de tu ejemplo sería:

> Cuando uno esta enamorado de una persona, esta se convierte en....

Comment: Se puede dar el uno sin el otro.